# Show a new alert with refreshing page after taking input from AlertController in Ionic3

Tags: android, angularjs, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using alertPromt where i have an input field. I have two options saying 'ok' & 'next' and 'cancel'.

If user clicks 'next' i need to capture the input value & add to the list behind & show again a new alert asking for more input from user in ionic3.

This should be a continious process.

**Issue Facing:** Currently for the first instance, the page refreshes & new alert is created. Now if i click on the 'next' button, the alert just stays forever & i cannot remove it from the view.

***Solutions Tried:*** I tried to dismiss the alert before calling the new one, but that gave me an error saying, remove view() some error. Still the issue is present.

I'm trying to run this code on the Android device. iOS device i have not tried.

Alert i'm using AlertController.

```
addNewItem(){
    this.showItemAddAlert();
  }

  showItemAddAlert(){
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      cssClass: 'custom-alert',
      title: 'Title',
      message: "Enter a name of the item.",
      inputs: [
        {
          id : 'alertInputId',
          name: 'itemName',
          placeholder: 'Item Name',
          value: ""
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          cssClass : 'first-button',
          text: 'Next',
          handler: data => {
             if(data.itemName !=""){
              this.addNewItem();

             }else{
                console.log('log here');
             }

          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: data => {
            if(data.itemName !=""){
              console.log('add input here');
            }

          }
        }
      ]
    });
    prompt.present()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we have first prompt where inital alert is been displayed i have an funtion like `this.myNewPromt(data)`  on next which carry the data of the input.

If you want you can call again the presentPrompt which will create a new alert;

```
 presentPrompt() {
      const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'title',
        inputs: [
          {
            name: 'Add',
            placeholder: 'Title'
          }
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: data => {
              console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: data => {

            }
          },{
            text: 'Next',
            handler: data => {
              this.myNewPromt(data);
            }
          }

        ]
      });
      alert.present();
    }



myNewPromt(data){
   if(data){
     //do your stuff
     this.presentPrompt();//which creats an new promt 
   }else{
     //do your stuff
     //if you don't want then we are not calling if you want you can call.
   }
}
```